# Windows 8.1 x64 Consistent BSOD - Details Included

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I am using a ASUS UX62LN-R4060H and consistently getting BSOD errors. I am not using it's built in bloatfull Windows. I am using Windows 8.1 x64. Got two kind of BSOD so far and here they are;

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tojC1.png]

Note: The second error occured only one time.

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump** to the desktop, create a zip, upload this zip (to a cloud service like OneDrive) and post a link to the zip here. I'll look at the dmp with the debugger

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is the [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FA173810A5BEAAB5!307&authkey=!AIEXjG5i-KC6IuU&ithint=file%2czip), my friend. Including lots of detail.

Answer (score 0):

You get the [Bug Check 0x9F: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When I look at the dmp, I see that the nVIDIA GPU driver for the Geforece 840M nvlddmkm.sys seams to cause it:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe000ac7e3540, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff803205ad960, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe000ad6761c0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

DRIVER_OBJECT: ffffe000abdde060

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53d0f1d4

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff801f0b5c000 pci

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck
nt!PopIrpWatchdog
nt!KiRetireDpcList
nt!KiIdleLoop


FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_image_pci.sys


0: kd> !irp ffffe000ad6761c0
Irp is active with 6 stacks 4 is current (= 0xffffe000ad676368)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [  0, 0]   0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [  0, 0]   0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [  0, 0]   0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[ 16, 2]   0 e1 ffffe000ac7e3540 00000000 fffff801f1c6837c-ffffd000c41e28f0 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\pci  dxgkrnl!DpiFdoPowerCompletionRoutine
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [ 16, 2]   0 e1 ffffe000ad9b11f0 00000000 fffff8031eb3df4c-ffffe000ae39aed8 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\nvlddmkm nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [  0, 0]   0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe000ae39aed8    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000


  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe000ad9b11f0 Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys
 \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffe000ad9b1340  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe000ad9b11c0

> ffffe000ac7e30b0  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe000ac6b9bf0  
  ffffe000ac7e3540  \Driver\pci        ffffe000ac7e3690  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe000ac7d5700 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1341&SUBSYS_15DD1043&REV_A2\4&1f8cb5be&0&00E4"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"

    Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
    Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Nov 12 21:51:31 2014 (5463C853)
```

Try to [update the driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/81392/en-us) and look if this fixes it.

Comment: Thanks 
@magicandre1981, but I am already using the last version of driver. Should I downgrade it? This makes no sense. Could be a physical problem with GPU?

Comment: try different drivers, also older ones

Comment: what is the result when using different drivers? Do you still get crashes?

Comment: I reinstalled Windows
Installed all Windows updates.
Installed Bitdefender Total Sec last version.
Installed latest driver from Nvidia.
Installed latest hotkey driver from Asus website.
Installed latest touchpad driver from Asus website.

Now seeing 5 unknown driver in device manager.
I feel my computer is a bit faster and more reliable now.

Tried reinstalling Windows and drivers before. But BSOD's occured everytime. As a difference now I didn't installed all drivers and no BSOD so far and I undecided about installing other drivers. Any advices?

Comment: share the new dmp files.

Comment: But I don't get a BSOD yet.